How to phrase selection_point in altair to do a selection_multi?
Altair now warns that selection_multi is deprecated and tells to use selection_point instead. I tried to replace it with same functionality with no success. How should I do it?

You can hold down the shift key, as per the end of this section of the docs https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#point-selections:
